# How can I retrieve users posts, add them with snapshots to table view - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to retrieve users follower information within an array. Then with that array get each users posts and then append them in my table view. All throughout this, I would like a snapshot listener to be added so that if a user likes a post the number will auto update. When I do this tho it appends every single update so one post will be shown about 5 times after an action such as liking it is performed which I do not want to happen. Could someone help me figure this out? I am using Xcode Swift. Thanks in advance!

```
class Posts {
    var postArray = [UserPost]()
    var db: Firestore!
    init() {
        db = Firestore.firestore()
    }
    func loadData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let sevenDaysAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
        self.postArray = []
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
        let displayUsername = user.displayName
        let userReference = db.collection("Users").document("User: \(displayUsername!)").collection("Connect").document("Following")
        userReference.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let documentData = document?.data(),
                var FollowerArray = documentData["Following"] as? [String] {
                FollowerArray.append(displayUsername!)
                FollowerArray.forEach {
                    self.db.collection("Users").document("User: \($0)").collection("Posts").whereField("timeOfPost", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: sevenDaysAgo!)
                        .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                            guard error == nil else {
                                print("*** ERROR: adding the snapshot listener \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                                return completed()
                            }
                            //self.postArray = []
                            // there are querySnapshot!.documents.count documents in the posts snapshot
                            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                                let post = UserPost(dictionary: document.data())
                                self.postArray.append(post)
                            }
                            completed()
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach and enable Firestore to tell you when child nodes (posts) have been added, modified or removed. Based on your code your structure is something like this:

```
Users
  uid
    //some user data like name etc
    Posts
      post_0
        likes: 0
        post: "some post 0 text"
      post_1
        likes: 0
        post: "text for post 1"
```

Let's have a class to store the Post in

```
class UserPostClass {
    var postId = ""
    var postText = ""
    var likes = 0

    init(theId: String, theText: String, theLikes: Int) {
        self.postId = theId
        self.postText = theText
        self.likes = theLikes
    }
}
```

and then an array to hold the UserPosts which will be the tableView dataSource

```
var postArray = [UserPostClass]()
```

then.. we need a block of code to do three things. First, when a new post is added to the database (or when we first start the app), add it to the dataSource array. Second, when a post is modified, for example another user likes the post, update the array to reflect the new like count. Third, if a post is deleted, remove it from the array. Here's the code that does all three......

```
func populateArrayAndObservePosts() {
    let uid = "uid_0" //this is the logged in user
    let userRef = self.db.collection("users").document(uid)
    let postsRef = userRef.collection("Posts")
    postsRef.addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = documentSnapshot else {
            print("err fetching snapshots")
            return
        }

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            let doc = diff.document
            let postId = doc.documentID
            let postText = doc.get("post") as! String
            let numLikes = doc.get("likes") as! Int

            if (diff.type == .added) { //will initially populate the array or add new posts
                let aPost = UserPostClass(theId: postId, theText: postText, theLikes: numLikes)
                self.postArray.append(aPost)
            }

            if (diff.type == .modified) { //called when there are changes
                //find the post that was modified by it's postId
                let resultsArray = self.postArray.filter { $0.postId == postId }
                if let postToUpdate = resultsArray.first {
                    postToUpdate.likes = numLikes
                }
            }

            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                print("handle removed \(postId)")
            }
        }
        //this is just for testing. It prints all of the posts
        // when any of them are modified
        for doc in snapshot.documents {
            let postId = doc.documentID
            let postText = doc.get("post") as! String
            let numLikes = doc.get("likes") as! Int
            print(postId, postText, numLikes)
        }
    }
}
```